# NuGet pack loses filenames when using wildcard on mono

Tags: ubuntu, mono, nuget, teamcity

I'm running TeamCity on ubuntu , and one build step creates a nuget package eg.

```
mono /opt/mono/NuGet.exe pack mypackage.nuspec
```

And this packages the site correctly only if I'm explicit about the files contained ie.

```
  <file src="Content/nancy-logo.png" target="lib/net45/Content/nancy-logo.png" />
```

These other paths don't quite work for me

```
  <file src="Content/**/*.*" target="lib/net45/Content/**/*.*" />
  <file src="Content/*.png" target="lib/net45/Content/*.png" />
  <file src="Content/*.jpg" target="lib/net45/Content/*.jpg" />
```

What I do get from a directory listing is this. Somewhere the filenames got mangled but haven't found where.

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 0 0  4096 Mar  8 03:44 %2A%2A
drwxr-xr-x 2 0 0  4096 Mar  8 03:44 %2A.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 0 20892 Jan 25  1992 nancy-logo.png
```

Thanks!

Comment: My case is a bit different. Nuget 2.8 being run under ubuntu does not handle file src starting with "..". Works well on Windows.